# How to export a module which works globally and for ES6 importing

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Currently I'm exporting like this:

```
module.exports = ReactCrop;
module.exports.getPixelCrop = getPixelCrop;
module.exports.makeAspectCrop = makeAspectCrop;
module.exports.containCrop = containCrop;
```

Basically taking a class (function) and adding the non-default exports to it.

The advantage of this is that the default export is a function `ReactCrop`. Meaning that when it's globally included via a `<script>` tag then `window.ReactCrop` is what you expect.

However if I change it to ES6:

```
export {
  ReactCrop,
  ReactCrop as default,
  getPixelCrop,
  makeAspectCrop,
  containCrop,
};
```

It's exported as an object. Which makes [eslint](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/558) and typescript happier. Otherwise you have to:

```
import * as ReactCrop from...
```

To make babel convert it to an object, as it stands this won't work:

```
import { getPixelCrop } from...
```

However when globally consuming the module it outputs this:

```
window.ReactCrop
{ReactCrop: ƒ, default: ƒ, getPixelCrop: ƒ, makeAspectCrop: ƒ, __esModule: true}
```

i.e. the user would have to do `window.ReactCrop.ReactCrop` to access the class.

**Question:** How can I satisfy both cases so that globally it's still a function because `window.ReactCrop.ReactCrop` is gross, but allow `{ partialImports }` and keep eslint and typescript happy by them finding an object with a default export?

PS I'm using webpack to export like so:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve('dist'),
  library: 'ReactCrop',
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
  filename: minified ? 'ReactCrop.min.js' : 'ReactCrop.js',
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I satisfy both cases so that globally it's still a function

This is not possible if you use a namespace import. A namespace object never is a function.

You can however do

```
import ReactCrop, * as ReactCropNs from "…";
Object.assign(ReactCrop, ReactCropNs);
window.ReactCrop = ReactCrop;
```

if you want to make it available globally in that form. I don't think there's a webpack option to do this automatically when exporting as a global.

> because `window.ReactCrop.ReactCrop` is gross

You can use `window.ReactCrop.default` instead.

Comment: Thanks I guess the only solution is a custom webpack exporter or multiple builds which make use of the extra package.json entries. I also exported as Component so global users can do `ReactCrop.Component` same as they would have to with `React.Component`. People rarely use globals so was too much faff to try and do it as a function.

Comment: @Dominic Yes, if you are able to write a custom webpack exporter than that's the solution to go for. Btw, what `React` is doing with their exports is mainly for ES5 compatibility, not necessarily a good ES6 practice.